# Sorting DataTable C#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sorting, datatable

I have a dataTable that contains **corresponding** names and scores. I want to sort it descending based on the scores.

Here is the code in DB.cs:

```
public class DB
    {
        public DataTable GetData()
        {
            string spName = "GetTime";
            Connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(spName, Connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Time");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Name"] = Convert.ToString(reader["name"]);
                dr["Time"] = Convert.ToInt32(reader["timeScore"]);
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            Connection.Close();
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

And this is on Form3.cs

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        private Form2 form2;
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadData();
        }

        public void loadData()
        {
            form2 = new Form2(); 
            DataTable dt2 = form2.db.GetData();
            dgvScore.DataSource = dt2;
        }
    }
```

What should I do to sort it without any `comparer` like in Java? I just want a simple algorithm answer.
Thank you for your appreciated help!

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to loop over the reader:

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
```

Then you can simply sort the defaultView:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "timeScore desc";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of inelegant to have to deal with a `DataView` when you want to sort a `DataTable` so here's a *really* simple and concise way to sort a **`DataTable`** instance .  I don't think the brevity breaks with semantic clarity, but please comment if you think it's confusing.

```
dt = new DataView(dt, "", "timeScore DESC",
                     DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable()
```